# Meaning of "Script delayed (xx min) waiting for quota" in Stackdriver when working with Google Sheet Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, stackdriver, quota, google-apps-script-addon

I have developed a Google Sheet Add-On "Jira Sheet Tools" which basically for my understanding should only be affected by the followings quotas from google according to the [quota dashboard](https://script.google.com/dashboard):

- Properties read/write
- URL Fetch calls
- URL Fetch data received

a)
The quota overview categories the limits in "Consumer", "Google Apps.." and "G-Suite".
How to read/understand this; would the limited apply to each user of my Add-On, or is the limit applied against My Developer account for all installed instance used by the peoples out there?

b)
In my related Stackdriver logs, i can see a lot (a few per day/hour) of error logs like:

> Script delayed (21.0 min) waiting for quota
>
> Script delayed (813.0 min) waiting for quota

I do not understand why and how.
For myself, i cant not reproduce any triggers for such logs when i use the Add-on myself.
It must be caused by other users of my add-on and i like to understand why this happens, what the impact for the user is and how i can improve my add-on to not cause such errors / delays.

Any insight and help is very much appriciated.
Thx in advance

Comment: I couldn't find any place where this is clearly documented by Google, but my wild guess is it's part of Scripts Quota Flexible Early Access program: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#flexible_quotas_early_access

Answer (score 2):

So I think that the main issue you're running into here is the trigger quota. This quota applies to your google developer account, and is not individualized for each add-on. As a matter of fact, all of these quotas are, as far as I know, applied to your account and not to each individual add-on or script. But when you manually run the add-on that was normally activated by the trigger, it does not count towards your trigger quota. Hope this helps!

Comment: I do however not use any triggers.